# Converting np.array of unix timestamps (dtype '<U21') to np.datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

I am looking to process a large amount of data, so I am interested in the fastest way to compute the following:

I have the below np.array as part of an np.ndarray, which I would like to convert from '<U21' to 'np.datetime64' (ms).

When I execute the following code on one entry, it works:

```
tmp_array[:,0][0].astype(int).astype('datetime64[ms]')
```

Result: numpy.datetime64('2019-10-09T22:54:00.000')

When I execute the same on the sub-array like so:

```
tmp_array[:,0] = tmp_array[:,0].astype(int).astype('datetime64[ms]')
```

I always get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The string provided for NumPy ISO datetime formatting was too short, with length 21
```

numpy version 1.22.4

```
array(['1570661640000', '1570661700000', '1570661760000'],dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: What do you expect the timestamp for these values to be?  I assume they are expressed in terms of timedelta expressed in microseconds from some epoch base.  without knowing what the base is and the delta factor it is hard to say.

Comment: Those are unix timestamps, ms since 1970-01-01.
Expected output: numpy.datetime64('2019-10-09T22:54:00.000')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a way to use the power of numpy to do this more efficiently but this approach works:
Given your tmp_array of the form:

```
array(['1570661640000', '1570661700000', '1570661760000'], dtype='<U21')
```

express the unix base date as:

```
db = np.datetime64('1970-01-01')
```

then create the desired datetime array by:

```
cnvrt_array = np.array([db + np.timedelta64(int(x), 'ms') for x in tmp_array])
```

This yields the array:

```
array(['2019-10-09T22:54:00.000', '2019-10-09T22:55:00.000',
       '2019-10-09T22:56:00.000'], dtype='datetime64[ms]')
```

As suggested by @FObersteiner, you can utilize the power of numpy to convert the array at a rate which is an order of magnitude faster than the list comprehension approach.

```
cvrted_array = tmp_array..astype(np.longlong).astype("datetime64[ms]")
```

which yields the same results as the list comprehension

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Unfortunately I am looking for the fastest way to obtain this calculation (maybe I'll add that to the question, sorry). I will be processing about 50gb of data so time matters here.

Comment: I am not sure you will find a solution giving much faster times  using the JypterNotebook's magic timer function %%timeit I get the following times for different size arrays:  ```Timing Tests
Array Length      Time
      100        25.4 us
    1,000        92.0 us
   10,000        2.66 ms
  100,000        13.5 ms
1,000,000        57.1 ms
```

Comment: Maybe you're right. I will give it a try, just thought that numpy builtin must work somehow and is supposed to be faster.

Comment: You maybe correct, I just don't use numpy often enough to provide a vectorized solution using numpy

Comment: there is no need for timedelta arithmetic here: numpy's datetime uses time since unix epoch anyway, so you can simply do a `.astype(int).astype("datetime64[ms]")` on the initial array.

Comment: Because of the size if the integers you need to use the np.longlong type as opposed to int.  This then becomes ```.astype(np.longlong).astype("datetime64[ms]")```

Comment: Using the ```.astype(np.longlong).astype("datetime64[ms]")``` method is at least an order of magnitude faster than the list comprehension.  Thanks@FObersteiner.  For your suggestion,